# Xpages Combobox -setting the default value

Tags: combobox, xpages

I have a combobox with values being populated from a managed bean like so:

```
keywordlist.setConnDB("jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xx:1433;DatabaseName=xxx");
keywordlist.setConnUserName("xxx");
keywordlist.setConnPassword("xxx");
keywordlist.setSQLQuery("SELECT DisplayText as Keyword From Glossary WHERE  SUBSTRING(DisplayText, 1, 2)= 'RV'");
keywordlist.keywords;
```

I'd like to be able to set the default to '--- Select ---', but no matter what I do the keyword list always picks the first of the returned keywords as the default.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another value pair (on first position), type "formula item" with the following SSJS return value:

```
"-- Select --|"
```

Notice the pipe!
That should display this at first position and should also be defaulted as "empty" is the default value. If not, set the "alias" (the value after the pipe) to something that you can define as default value porperty for the combo item.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. That gave me the same results as before. Namely, "--Select--" appears as the first item in the drop down list, but the default selected item when viewing the page is the first item returned in the list of keywords by the bean. I tried this with and without the alias (setting the default value to the alias).

Comment: Oliver, I got it to work. It had to do with how I had the field bound to session scope instead of to the document data source. For some reason that caused it to fail. It's now working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you're binding to the bean directly.  You might have to add that value to your keyword list itself.  I think I have an example of this in a NotesIn9 show:  http://notesin9.com/index.php/2014/03/13/notesin9-138-xpages-combobox-improvements/

I'm not sure.  If I don't have a default in the java code you can probably see how it might be done.

Try that.  If that doesn't work at all then maybe you don't bind the combo box to the bean directly.  Maybe bind it to a viewScope var...  since that can be anything it'll take a blank...  then you just need to move the viewScope var value back up to your bean in the onChange event or something.

Just a quick thought...

Comment: Thanks David. I got it working. See my reply below to Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the following pattern could be a start point for such a combobox:

```
    <xp:comboBox
        id="comboBox1"
        defaultValue=""
        value="#{document1.someField}">
        <xp:selectItem
            itemLabel="--- Select ---"
            itemValue=""></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            // Your SSJS code...
            // Should return some kind of list...
            return items;
}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:comboBox>
```

Alternatively, you can grab the keyword values from a Java bean:

```
        <xp:selectItems value=#{yourBean.yourValue}></xp:selectItems>
```

Still, it's important to return a list value. It might also have "label|value" format.

Comment: Thank you Serdar. I figured out the problem. Oliver's solution was very similar to yours.